# Let $\Omega = \{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C \mid 1\le x\le 2, 4 \pi \le y \le 7 \pi \}$. Describe the image of $\Omega$ under the map $f(z)=e^z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Omega = \{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C \mid 1\le x\le 2, 4 \pi \le y \le 7 \pi \}$. Describe the image of $\Omega$ under the map $f(z)=e^z$.

How should I start to figure out how $f$ maps $\Omega$? The image is symbolically $$f(\Omega)= \{e^{x+iy} \mid x+iy \in \Omega \}$$ and by the conditions on $x$ and $y$ should I start by fixing either $x$ or $y$? If $x=1$ and $y \in [4\pi, 7\pi]$, then how can I figure out the geometric meaning of this under $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the image of $z= x + iy\in \mathbb{C}$ under $\exp$ is at a distance $e^x$ from the origin and has argument $y$ by definition. Consequently, for fixed $x\in[1,2]$, the image of the set $\Omega_x := \{x + iy \:|\:4\pi \leqslant y \leqslant 7\pi\}$ under $\exp$ is the circle of radius $e^x$ centred at the origin since points with argument in $[4\pi, 7\pi]$ cover the entire circle. Since $\Omega = \cup_{x\in[1,2]}\Omega_x$,
$\exp(\Omega)$ is the annulus centred at the origin with inner radius $e$ and outer radius $e^2$.

Comment: Could you explain why the image of $\Omega_x := \{x + iy \:|\:4\pi \leqslant y \leqslant 7\pi\}$ is the circle of radius $e^x$? I can see why the radius is $e^x$, but why does it map to the circle?

Comment: Can you see why the (an) argument of the image of $x+iy$ under $\exp$ is $y$? Once that is clear, try tracing the image of $x+iy$ as $y$ is increased from $4\pi$ to $7\pi$.